# Keras Softmax issues

Tags: keras, softmax

I am new to Keras and am bit confused at the moment:

```
def get_compiled_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, input_shape = (1000,), activation='relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(41, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform')
])

    model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I then call my model as follows:

```
model = get_compiled_model()
for i in range(10):
     model.fit(train_object, epochs=10)
     test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_object, verbose=2)
```

I keep getting 0 accuracy even after a lot of training. I think it is because the model is hardmaxing from the start:

```
for row in test_object.take(1):
    row
print(model.predict(row[0])[0])
```

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

This behavior happens even at the beginning which is confusing since we would expect something with decimals rather than all 0's and 1's.

Any help would be appreciated. To rephrase the question I am confused to why the model is hardmaxing instead of softmazing.

0

UPDATE: messed around with the size of the model, decreasing the size of the model gave us:

```
array([0.02439025, 0.02439031, 0.02439018, 0.02439029, 0.02439014, 0.02438815, 0.02439025, 0.02439022, 0.02439038, 0.02439022, 0.02439025, 0.02439038, 0.0243915 , 0.02439023, 0.02439109, 0.02438496, 0.02439068, 0.02439134, 0.02439025, 0.02439033, 0.02438724, 0.02439025, 0.02439067, 0.02439027, 0.02439025, 0.02439088, 0.02439021, 0.02439019, 0.02439023, 0.02439035, 0.02439059, 0.02439025, 0.02439438, 0.02439116, 0.02439019, 0.02439001, 0.02439013, 0.02439059, 0.02439025, 0.02439023, 0.02439026], dtype=float32)
```

which is the desired effect. Any idea why larger net causes it to hardmax?

UPDATE 2:

```
def get_compiled_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(124, input_shape = (1000,), activation='relu', 
    kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape = (1000,), activation='relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(41, activation='relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax(-1)
 ])

    model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    return model
```

The current issues is that it converges to having the same weights on all the options all the time:

Comment: what does train_object and test object look like?

Comment: just a tabular dataset in the form of an iterator data type: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((?, 1000), (?,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>

Comment: would add a Softmax layer instead of using an activation function, i am not really sure but the axis might be causing some unexpected results, such as softmaxing on batchsize axis in stead of row dimension

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more descriptive. If you remove the useless repetition of the tag information, it leaves *Issues* as the title, which clearly doesn't provide any information. Your title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will be useful to a future user of this site who is scanning a list of search results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is train_object? It's possible you forgot to specify targets, e.g., the y parameters to the fit function.

```
fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False)
```